# dsl modem with wifi in bridge mode to firewall/router, how to get wifi to downstream network

Tags: wireless-access-point, bridge, dsl-modem

Comtrend CT-5361T setup in Bridge Mode to pass traffic to downstream ZyWall2PLUS router/firewall. Works good and downstream computers on that network have access to internet.

The Comtrend has a wifi access point but in bridge mode it is not allowing wifi clients to access internet. The user manual has a little bit about "wireless bridge" but I don't understand it.

It says AP Mode: Wireless Bridge or Access Point. WB will disable access point functionality. Does this mean a user cannot connect to the Internet with their wireless device?

If I select AP, then is it supposed to allow users to connect to dsl modem access point wirelessly, then it sends all requests downstream to the ZW router?

Or, is WB mean to join 2 diff access point devices together to the same LAN, and it has nothign to do with teh dsl modem being in bridged mode.

Maybe the dsl modem AP is just "supposed to work" and it's the job of the downstream router to assign an ip via DHCP, which would then give the wireless user access to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

Bridge mode means that it is simply passing the connection straight through and not routing anything at all.  You should use the wifi on your router that the bridge is passing the connection to.  Your Comtrend should be acting like a chessy passthrough modem.